# remember passowrd works in ff but not in ie and chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, passwords, google-chrome

It seems that my html login form supports "remember password" in ff but not in ie and chrome. Can anybody tell me why? Here's the code:

```
<form name="login_form" id="login_form" action="" method="POST">
    <div class="login_line">name<input name="user_name" id="user_name_id" size="16" maxlength="16" value="" type="text"></div>
    <div class="login_line">password<input name="password" id="password_id" size="16" maxlength="16" type="password"></div>
    <div class="login_line">&nbsp;<input class="icon icon_accept" value="login" onclick="javascript:handleFunction('action_login', document.getElementById('user_name_id').value, document.getElementById('password_id').value); return false;" type="submit"></div>
</form> <!-- login_form -->
```

I've checked my settings in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `onsubmit` instead of `onclick` for forms... I'm not sure if pressing Enter on a textbox will fire `onclick` on all browsers.

```
<form name="login_form" id="login_form" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="handleFunction('action_login', document.getElementById('user_name_id').value, document.getElementById('password_id').value); return false;">
    <div class="login_line">name<input name="user_name" id="user_name_id" size="16" maxlength="16" value="" type="text"></div>
    <div class="login_line">password<input name="password" id="password_id" size="16" maxlength="16" type="password"></div>
    <div class="login_line">&nbsp;<input class="icon icon_accept" value="login" type="submit"></div>
</form> <!-- login_form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work as the code is correct. Check browser settings?

Comment: I've checked my settings in IE and Chrome

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS html,body change overflow-x = hidden to just overflow = hidden