# HTML: Chrome save password

Tags: html, google-chrome, authentication, passwords

Firefox and IE ask me to save the password.
Why doesn't Chrome ask me? What do I have to change?

```
<body>
    <form action="" name="formlogin" id="formlogin">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />   
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> 
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want that unsafe password helper?

Comment: Chrome doesn't like you spelling as Chrome saves my passwords for me.

Does is save any passwords?

Maybe this will help:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=95606

Comment: I must use it. It's not my choice.

Comment: Yes it saves some passwords from other sites.

Comment: FYI: This article about [Chrome PasswordManager PasswordFormManager](http://tech.pro/tutorial/828/how-google-chrome-stores-passwords) gives some insight how passwords are stored in Chrome's SQLite database and that they are encrypted using a `CryptProtectData` method. Since it is 6 years old i wonder if currently chrome stores the passwords online as well.

Comment: Possibe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs a destination. Just assign *action*.
For example create a file called "test.html" and then:

```
<body>
    <form action="test.html" name="formlogin" id="formlogin">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />    
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> 
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this question has already been adressed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891719/remember-passowrd-works-in-ff-but-not-in-ie-and-chrome)

```
<form name="formlogin" id="formlogin" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="handleFunction('action_login', document.getElementById('username').value, document.getElementById('password').value); return false;">
        Username: <input name="username" id="username" size="16" maxlength="16" value="" type="text">
        Password: <input name="password" id="password" size="16" maxlength="16" type="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> <!-- login_form -->
```