# How-to enable the built-in password saving prompt in Chrome with Vue.js 2, BootstrapVue, and axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, axios, bootstrap-vue

I’m turning mad, because I can’t make the **Chrome Password Manager** ask for password saving with a form. Let’s say that Firefox saves both username/ e-mail and password without issues: **Chrome**, on the other hand, ignores every change I've made.

I already know that Google published [the best practices for this achievement](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/save-forms), but I can’t use the Fetch API to login and I wasn’t able to adapt the suggested code to `axios`, I got just an error message, saying that I need to store credentials in either a `passwordCredentialData` or `HTMLFormElement`, trying to use the `PasswordCredential` constructor (no matter how I pass those credentials).

Anyway, the form itself should support the browser’s built-in functionality. Here’s a sample of the output code:

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required="required" autocomplete="username email">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required="required" autocomplete="current-password">
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

This should have been enough, but it’s a form generated by Vue.js and BootstrapVue. I’m already aware of the known issues with AJAX. Also, [I tried adding `action="/login"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431783/html-chrome-save-password) and `method="post"` in the `<form>` element tag and it hasn’t changed anything. Then, I tried with `new-password` – instead of `current-password` – too… nothing has changed.

Of course, being generated by BootstrapVue, the sources are a bit different.

```html
<b-form @submit.prevent="handleLogin">
  <b-form-group>
    <b-form-input autocomplete="username email" id="email" name="email" required type="email" v-model="form.email"></b-form-input>
    <b-form-input autocomplete="current-password" id="password" name="password" required type="password" v-model="form.password"></b-form-input>
  </b-form-group>
  <b-button type="submit"></b-button>
</b-form>
```

I removed classes and other pieces of code not involved in the issue, such as placeholders and labels, for better reading. I called [an `onsubmit` event as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891719/remember-passowrd-works-in-ff-but-not-in-ie-and-chrome).

I learnt that Google activates the Chrome Password Manager *after* a successful redirect (a Vue.js route redirection, in this case) — so the relative logic is crucial. I tried adding `{ withCredentials: true }` to the `axios` request properties, but as I said it fails to create a new `PasswordCredential` constructor, because of the data format. It’d be ideal to use Vue.js `form.email` and `form.password` pre-defined models, although it also fails with a dedicated `FormData` object.

```js
async handleLogin() {
  await axios
    .post("/auth", {
      email: this.form.email,
      password: this.form.password
    },
    {
      withCredentials: true
    })
      .then({
        ...
      })
      .catch({
        ...
      });
}
```

Above, the first lines of the method are used to handle the login. I think that this could be just a starting point, since Google Developers show how-to store credentials with the Fetch API and the `PasswordCredential` constructor. I browsed the SO archive for weeks, but I still can’t go any further; making a syncronous call doesn’t solve the issue, if you’re minding. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT • Is it ever possible that **Google Password Manager** doesn’t work just because I’m on an unsecure area (a local domain without or with an unsigned SSL certificate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK (reading [this thread in **Google Help Center**](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9675878?hl=en)) although the code below should work, it actually doesn’t if the related domain hasn’t a valid SSL certificate.

```
async handleLogin() {
  await axios
    .post("/auth", {
      email: this.form.email,
      password: this.form.password
    },
    {
      withCredentials: true
    })
      .then({
        ...
      })
      .then(() => {
        if (window.PasswordCredential) {
          const passwordCredential = new PasswordCredential({ id: this.form.email, password: this.form.password });
          navigator.credentials.store(passwordCredential);
        }
        ...
      })  
      .catch({
        ...
      });
}
```

This has been inspired by [a newer version of the official documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/credential-management-sample/blob/master/static/scripts/app.js) and should work for those who provide a valid SSL certificate only. Right now, there isn’t a way to overcome this issue as of [#142818](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142818).

EDIT • If your developing site or webapp is under `localhost`, then you may want to enable “Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.” from `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`.

EDIT • Unfortunately, enabling `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` for custom domains doesn’t change anything (and makes Chrome even more unstable).